# Google Chrome @font-face problem

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

I have problem with pages that have @font-face with Chrome, for example if I go to page http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/, then my computer freezes and I cannot do anything for a while. And this happends just with pages that have @font-face CSS property. So if I want to use @font-face on my own pages, is it possible to avoid this Chrome issue somehow?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? And what OS is it installed on?

Comment: [Doesn't happen for me in v16.] This might be migrated to SuperUser, but really it seems like just a [support issue](http://support.google.com/chrome/?hl=en). If those pages don't have a solution(I don't spend much time in Chrome), there's a link to their support forum/list in the sidebar.

Comment: Version is 16.0.912.63 m and I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 32bit 4GB  RAM Intel U7300 @ 1.3GHz.

Answer (score 2):

It happens for me too. I'd report it here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry if I were you.

I wouldn't let it stop you using it. Chrome gets update so often that it should go away so soon. If it were an IE bug I'd be recommending you find a way round it as IE gets updated so infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely a Windows 7 issue:

1. It is not just Chrome that freezes, the whole computer, even the mouse pointer freezes
2. Some people reported the same with FireFox
3. I have myself noticed the issue at PhotoShop startup (*reading fonts...* stage)
4. If your computer choked once, it won't again no matter how many times the browser is closed or re-opened. But restarting the computer brings back the problem